# Sum of sines and cosines from DFT

Tags: python, numpy

I have a signal and want to reconstruct it from its spectrum as a sum of sines and/or cosines. I am aware of the inverse FFT but I want to reconstruct the signal in this way.

An example would look like this:

```py
sig = np.array([1, 5, -3, 0.7, 3.1, -5, -0.5, 3.2, -2.3, -1.1, 3, 0.3, -2.05, 2.1, 3.05, -2.3])

fft = np.fft.rfft(sig)
mag = np.abs(fft) * 2 / sig.size
phase = np.angle(fft)

x = np.arange(sig.size)
reconstructed = list()
for x_i in x:
    val = 0
    for i, (m, p) in enumerate(zip(mag, phase)):
        val += ...  # what's the correct form?
    reconstructed.append(val)
```

What's the correct code to write in the next-to-last line?

Comment: whats the equation for signal reconstruction? would imagine something like `m[0]*np.cos(...) + ...`

Comment: I think he's trying to fill in that one line in his code with a question mark.

Comment: @FrankYellin ah, missed that

Comment: @MattDMo.  I edited the question to make it more explicit.  I was confused at first, too.

Comment: So you want a single line equation for converting magnitude and phase into a time dependent signal.  Is this correct?

Comment: @itprorh66 pretty much yes, doesn't have to be a single line tho

Comment: Isn't that the purpose of the inverse FFT?  Why do you want to reinvent the wheel?  Have you found any mathematical definition's of how that could be accomplished?